# split more than one files tkinter frame

Tags: python, split, tkinter, frame

I look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557028/4754167). I can split my page (frame) into two file. For example, this is my first file: `main.py`

```
from Tkinter import *
from halsatu import *
class Biasa(Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo):
            frame = F(container, self)
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')
            self.frames[F] = frame
        self.show_frame(StartPage)
    def show_frame(self, c):
        frame = self.frames[c]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = Label(self, text='Ini halaman Awal')
        label.pack()

        button = Button(self, text='ke Halaman 1',
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()
        button2 = Button(self, text='ke Hal. 2',
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()

class PageTwo(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = Label(self, text='Sekarang \nIni halaman Dua lho..')
        label.pack()

        button = Button(self, text='ke Halaman 1',
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        button.pack()
        button2 = Button(self, text='ke Hal. Awal',
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button2.pack()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Biasa()
    app.mainloop()
```

Then this is my halsatu.py:

```
from Tkinter import *
class PageOne(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = Label(self, text='Kalau yang Ini halaman Satuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu')
        label.pack()

        button = Button(self, text='ke Halaman Awal',
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        button.pack()
        button2 = Button(self, text='ke Hal. 2',
            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        button2.pack()
```

That code can run. But when I go to pageone, I can't go back to StartPage again. How to split so many pages (frames) into separate files?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes. When I go to PageOne, and then I click the first button, this error appear: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1489, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/muktyas/Dropbox/py/tk/150709oop/0914/halsatu.py", line 10, in <lambda>
    command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
NameError: global name 'StartPage' is not defined

Comment: Yea I thought so, `StartPage` or `PageTwo` is not imported in your `halsatu.py` so they would not be accessible

Comment: whether the code is in one file or several is irrelevant. What you want to do doesn't depend on how many files you use.

Answer (score 1):

You are already passing in a controller to `PageOne`, so that can be the mechanism to raise pages. My recommendation is to make it possible to reference the pages by name rather than by class, and then give the controller a method that accepts the name and raises that page. This way your pages don't have to import each other, making for a looser coupling.

It would look something like this:

```
class Biasa(Tk):
    ...
    def show_page(self, page_name):
        for F in self.frames:
            if F.__name__ == page_name:
                self.show_frame(F)
                return

class PageOne(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        button = Button(..., command=lambda: controller.show_page("StartPage"))
        ...
```